# sdkman, grails 2.4.5 and Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings error

Tags: grails, sdkman

```
 Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/katarina/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.5/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/katarina/Workspace/myApp/target/work/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Error SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
```

The error says it found multiple bindings in

myApp: `/home/katarina/Workspace/myApp/target/work/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class`

sdkman: `/home/katarina/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.4.5/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class`.

How do I resolve this? I think I should exclude at least one of them but how?